# Trying to make child hover different to parent

Tags: html, css, hover, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm trying to create an ul where when hovered, opacity moves to 0.4, however when hovering on the li element the opacity for that individual element returns to 1.

Is this possible? Heads up I'm using Fomantic UI (Semantic UI fork)

```
    <div class="four wide column">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="item" href="">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  &:hover{
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

}

li{
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;

  &:hover{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not using the `&` and writing the rules for hovering outside of the `ul` and `li` selectors makes the example to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your message, unfortunately that has not solved the problem

    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 0px;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
          ul:hover{
        opacity: 0.4;
      }

    li{
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    li:hover{
      opacity: 1;
    }

Comment: I uploaded a video of the situation on my device using your code: https://streamable.com/28i5a. As you can see, when I hover on an `li` element, the opacity persist.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this, the child needed to be included with the parent instruction as below

```
ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 0px;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

          ul:hover **li a**{
        opacity: 0.4;
      }

    li{
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      transition: 0.5s;




    a{
      font-family: montserrat;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

      a:hover {
        opacity: 1!important;
      }

    }
```